Need help building a wireless router that offers /30 public IP range through DHCP
I have a block of public IP addresses and I want to build a router using my Raspberry Pi to offer those public IP addresses to my devices behind CGNAT.
The topology
[Server](wireguard addr = 10.0.0.1/24)
      –Wireguard–>
[Router] (wireguard addr = 10.0.0.2) 
      –>
[AP] (wlan0=x.y.z.0/30)
Current status

ip addr has confirmed that the address for wlan0 is x.y.z.0/30
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0 is on the router end
The Wi-Fi hotspot and DHCP server are functional, with the default
gateway set to x.y.z.0, and connected devices receive addresses in
the range x.y.z.0+n.
I can see the client on the ARP table with arp -a
When I ping addresses in the x.y.z.0/30 range from an other server, I
can see the incoming packets on the router’s Wireguard interface.
IPv4 forwarding is enabled on the router (net.ipv4.ip_forward=1).
If I do ping 8.8.8.8 on router it won't get any replies after
WireGuard interface is up (Packets captured on server WireGuard
interface have source IP 10.0.0.2) but ping -I x.y.z.0 8.8.8.8 will
work (Packets captured on server WireGuard interface have source IP
x.y.z.0).
Packets are not being forwarded to wlan0, nor in the opposite
direction.
Running command iptables -A FORWARD -d x.y.z.0+n -o wlan0 -j ACCEPT
can force packets to forward to wlan0, but iptables -A FORWARD -s x.y.z.0+n -o wg0 -j ACCEPT doesn't work for the reverse direction.

Can anyone offer any hints on why this isn’t working as expected? Thanks!

Is "AP" your outside (WAN) interface? I wouldn't expect it to have a .0/30 address

I'm going to be honest, I don't understand your end goal. Well, let's say, I don't understand why using NAT/NAPT from the carrier router is not enough.
I also think you lack some knowledge about networking with IPv4. It most likely means you are running commands and tools you don't really understand. I would suggest to learn about IPv4 first.
I have remarks:

You shouldn't configure a network address to a host. This is a specific special address. So you either assigned x.y.z.1 or x.y.z.2 to wlan0 but not x.y.z.0. Meaning it leaves you only with one address to be assigned to a host through DHCP since x.y.z.3 is the broadcast address.
https://superuser.com/questions/379451/why-can-a-network-address-not-be-a-valid-host-address#379474

Adding rules to the FORWARD chain of the filter table in Netfilter will not force packets to go anywhere. Your rules allows those packet to do so. You can set the default policy to ACCEPT for the FORWARD chain ar first. And then defined the correct rules to apply with a DENY default policy once everything is working as expected. If you want to choose yourself where should a packet goes depending on the destination and source addresses, you can edit the routing table or do policy routing.

Just paste the config and the command output. Your interpretation might leaves important data out for us to help you out. You might have missed or misinterpreted something.


As for insight, I would check the routing table of each host (after setting wlan0 to a valid address). When a response packet cannot make the route back, it usually is a routing misconfiguration. And since you are using IPv4 addresses routed on the internet, the packet is maybe sent to the wrong gateway somewhere.

Thanks for your reply, the problem has been solved. Turns out it was caused by the DHCP server. After manually configuring the IP address on wlan0, I was able to get clients connected to the internet with manual IP configuration.
Regarding your remarks:

Yes, I know it’s uncommon to use a network address and that’s probably the reason that the dhcp server malfunctioned, but since I only have a /30 block, I’d like to use as many of my IP addresses as possible.
It’s just an experiment to see if there are any potential problems. I’m definitely not going to rely on iptables for this.

